Why do email links in Reminders point to the wrong email when shared from Mail on iOS/macOS?
When I share an email from the Mail app to Reminders by highlighting the subject line, selecting “Share,” and choosing “Reminders,” a task is created with the email’s subject line and a link. However, the link always points to a random, unrelated email from the distant past rather than the email I intended to "share".
This issue occurs on both iOS and macOS. On macOS, drag-and-drop creates the correct link, but sharing via the menu does not.
How can I fix this or ensure that the link points to the correct email?
